# Does React-Bootstrap needs Bootstrap dependencies

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use react-bootstrap in my project, the thing is does react-bootstrap needs bootstrap dependency to be installed along. If that's needed why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Getting Started](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/) page explains it. You need the bootstrap CSS, either loaded from a CDN or installed via NPM's `bootstrap` package. You don't need the JavaScript, since React Bootstrap replaces it.